# How to open a WebElement from a Hoover Menu Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Hello I'm new using selenium and I was trying to execute some tests from a web page.

This is my code:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\DRIVERS\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //Open Portal Fiscal
    driver.get("http://150.23.110.111/Retenciones/");
    //Find what field and enter the user and password
    driver.findElement(By.id("frmLogin:txtUsr")).sendKeys("arrubio");
    driver.findElement(By.id("frmLogin:txtPwd")).sendKeys("gnp00gnp");
    driver.findElement(By.id("frmLogin:butLogin")).click();
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("")));
```

I can enter to the page without problem and I can enter the user and the password to login, but there's a hoover menu on the next page that I can´t use and stops my automatic execution.

This is the xpath and the csspath:

xpath: /html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span

csspath: html body div#content div#leftPanel.ui-layout-unit.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-layout-west.blankBck div.ui-layout-unit-content.ui-widget-content form#j_id1833690111_27e067e8.blankBck div#j_id1833690111_27e067e8:j_id1833690111_27e0678e.ui-menu.ui-menubar.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-helper-clearfix ul.ui-menu-list.ui-helper-reset li.ui-widget.ui-menuitem.ui-corner-all.ui-menu-parent.ui-menuitem-active ul.ui-widget-content.ui-menu-list.ui-corner-all.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-menu-child.ui-shadow li.ui-menuitem.ui-widget.ui-corner-all a.ui-menuitem-link.ui-corner-all span.ui-menuitem-text

And this is the element that appears inspecting the "Búsqueda" button.

```html
<ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu" style="display: block; height: auto; z-index: 1013; left: 0px; top: 28px;">
<li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
<a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="/Retenciones/main/faces/m_evaPuntual.xhtml" style="width:120px" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">Búsqueda</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
</ul>
```

How can I select and open the button "Búsqueda" from the hoover menu?

Thanks for the attention :)

Answer (score 2):

try using:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for menu"));
WebElement item = driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("css selector values for Búsqueda"));
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(item ).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code using `action class`

```
WebElement menu_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_menu_xpath"));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   //Explicit wait method, wait for web-element till 10 seconds so, your driver should able to find the web-element.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your_submemu_xpath"))));

WebElement sub_menu_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your_submemu_xpath"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu_element).moveToElement(sub_menu_element).click().build().perform();
```

**Explanation:**

1) First locate the `menu element`

2) Provide `explicit wait` method for few seconds so your driver may able to find the `sub_menu_element` that you want to go with.

3) After explicit wait locate the `sub_menu element`, that you want to go with.

4) Using `Action class` try to move element from `menu to sub menu`.

Comment: Have you try this code? Does my explanation of code helped you?