# movehover from Selenium on a dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium

Below is the code in the HTML

```
<div id="pMenu_root_10" class="itemBorder" style="position: absolute; left: 809px; top: 0px; width: 58px; height: 98px; z-index: 1000; background: rgb(190, 213, 231) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; cursor: default;" onmouseover="pMenu.over('root',10)" onmouseout="pMenu.out('root',10)" onclick="pMenu.click('root',10)">
   <div class="lowText" style="font-size: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; color: #0066CC; position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; width: 56px; height: 96px">Reports</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to hover the mouse from selenium to so that i can select one of the sub menu present. But my selenium is not able to get the element

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='pMenu_root_10']/div[text()='Reports']"));     
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(ele).perform();
```

i tried using the abosulte Xpath as well given by the Firepath

```
.//*@id='loginFormName']/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/img
```

Please help me in finding the issue

Below is the error returned

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@id='pMenu_root_10']/div[text()='Reports']"}
```

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242950/how-to-open-a-webelement-from-a-hoover-menu-selenium-java/43247339#43247339

Comment: Still giving the same error. It is still not getting the pMenu_root_10

Comment: Please pass the error and can you please share your site url?

Comment: THis is the company website with login crediantials, so cant share it. If you want i can pass the html code

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='pMenu_root_10']/div"}

Comment: please note when i try to search the tag via xpath in ff, i am able to find this element

Comment: From the above html, i can not help you properly. Because when i try to hover the element, nothing is happened.

Comment: can i mail you the code?email id plz?it will contain the url

Comment: I have checked your code, your code seems to be ok. When i try to open the url, it does not allow me to access the site. I just want to check your xpath. Some where in your code you have used absolute xpath, please try to use relative xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enter **username** and **password** to the site, use below mentioned code to access the sub menu.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();

WebDriverWait after_login = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   
after_login.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='parent_25']/a[contains(text(), 'Projects, Delivery & Sales')]"))));

WebElement menu_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='parent_25']/a[contains(text(), 'Projects, Delivery & Sales')]"));
menu_element.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='parentGroup_25']/..//div[@class='hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu']/a[contains(text(), 'Integrated Project Management System')]"))));

WebElement sub_menu_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='parentGroup_25']/..//div[@class='hreftheme_AppLinks_sub_links_Li_Megamenu']/a[contains(text(), 'Integrated Project Management System')]"));
sub_menu_element.click();

WebDriverWait IPMS_sub_menu_launch_button = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/..//following::td/img[@alt='Launch IPMS']"))));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/..//following::td/img[@alt='Launch IPMS']")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);

String childWindow = (String) driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];  
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);   // Switch to newly opened window. 
System.out.println("Switch to new tab.");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginFormName']/..//following::td/img[@src='images/go_on.gif']")).click(); // After New tab, Webelement is easily accessible.
Thread.sleep(8000);

   try
   {
      String report_page_url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
      System.out.println(report_page_url);

      String url = "https://ipmsapp.ultimatix.net/webipms/calhome_new.jsp";

      if(report_page_url.equals(url))
      {
          System.out.println("I am on the report page.");
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("Report page not open.");
   }
```